# How can I copy and deep copy a muldtidimesional array with [][][] structure

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array => `mda [][][]`. What I want to do is copy 
`mda [0][all][all]` to `mda [ 1 ][][]` and then make some operations on  the newly created `mda[ 1 ][][]` section. 
I checked stack overflaw and all other tutorials on the internet and came across tutorials with `[][]` structure not the `[][][]` structure. I'll accept links as answers as long as they specifically solve the problem and I am not seeking long iterations and that kind of solution. Probably a `clone()` or `copy()` type of function solution is what I am seeking. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: is there really that much of a difference, when you found a question about a deep copy of an `array`, compared to a deep copy of an `array` of `arrays`?

Comment: I cannot edit your question but here are a few recommendations for improving the question: 1- you can give us the link to the solution you mention, so we know what you are talking about. 2 - you can mark the code snippets with the appropriate tags, so we can read more easily. 3 - You can use paragraphs to separate different sections of your question, so we can scan the text. 4 - when you post a question, make sure it can be understood by a [duck](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Everyone is busy. Help them help you.

Comment: My friend turzifer thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to deep copy (which is what you want) a multi dimensional array in Java is to iterate.

So in your case you'll end up with something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // First we create the mda:
    String[][][] mda = new String[2][][];

    // Now we fill the mda[0][0][0] with 8
    mda[0] = new String[][] { {"8"} };

    // We make a deepCopy of mda[0] and put it in mda[1]:
    mda[1] = deepCopy(mda[0]);

    // Now we change the value of mda[1][0][0]:
    mda[1][0][0] = "42";

    // And here we show it is truly a copy, mda[0][0][0] isn't changed:
    System.out.println(mda[0][0][0]);
    System.out.println(mda[1][0][0]);
}

private static String[][] deepCopy(String[][] input) {
    String[][] output = new String[input.length][];
    for(int index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {
        output[index] = input[index].clone();
    }
    return output;
}
```

The output will be a true copy:

```
8
42
```

Comment: What a Shot Roy! Thank you for your time!! :)

Comment: The deepCopy bit is showing in RED and it is inside a method in a class formation. The mda is a String array.                                                 pozisyon[donsay] = deepCopy(pozisyon[donsay-1]); is the code I made. The declaration is String[][][] pozisyon = {

            {

                    {"a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2"},
                    {"a7", "b7", "c7", "d7", "e7", "f7", "g7", "h7"},
                    {"a1", "h1"},
                    {"a8", "h8"},
                    {"b1", "g1"},
                    etc.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is showing in red > meaning it doesn't compile? If you change the method from int[][] to String[][] it should work fine given your example.

Comment: I am very sorry but it gives the following error:                                   Error:(101, 36) error: cannot find symbol method deepCopy(String[][])
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED

Comment: The deepCopy is now made to work with int arrays, you'll need to change it to work with String arrays.

Comment: I am sorry but how exactly is that done can you explain or provide a source? Best Regards. By the way I copied your code to a class method structure it did not recognize deepCopy again. Android Studio 1.4.1

Comment: I've changed the example above to use a String[][][].